# Passport.js not setting session on different domain request

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am using passport.js local strategy for login but not being able to set session. I have two servers i.e. **localhost:3000** is for node and another is localhost:4200. Here I want to set session on request from **localhost:4200**.

Comment: the 4200 should receive a cookie from the 3000 once it successfully logs in. And then should keep sending that cookie in each request. Are you getting a cookie at all?

Comment: Once logged in it doesn't set cookie on 4200 because on next request it shows unauthorized user. Here I am using req.isAuthenticated() it always returns false on all request hit on server after logged in.

Comment: well, you will have to add some code to see where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

How your session is configured ??

Here's an example of how you can do it.

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'some secret that must not be explicit in code',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
  })
}))
```